# SharePoint search results not getting displayed to any user after adding new content source

Tags: 2013, display-template, sharepoint-search, result-source, result-types

I just added a new Content Source, Result Source, and Result Type in my on-premise SharePoint 2013 Search center. My search center displays results based on result types. When I search content, I can find it and is displayed correctly based on my result type. However, when any other user tries to find the content, s/he gets "Sorry something went wrong". The user can still see refiners but no results.

When the user goes to respective item template tab, they can see the results. Am I missing publishing anything? I did publish the results item template.

Comment: What does your ULS log say when the user gets "Sorry something went wrong"?

Comment: I am unable to find any errors per say. Any specific keyword should look for?

Comment: Hard to say from this end, but if you have the correlation-ID you can get the error stack in the ULS

Comment: I am just getting Something went wrong. However, all users who are site collection admins on my search center can search and view results.

Comment: I am getting the below errors in ULS logs

The type of parameter value, System.Object is not supported 9acc599e-5ff6-b0bc-75e9-1ec4b2de0328
Cannot get EdmTypeReference for type System.Object 9acc599e-5ff6-b0bc-75e9-1ec4b2de0328

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a bug in the Display Template. Try resetting your Result Type Rule to default and then have your users search. If it works implement your rules until you discover which of your Display Templates is failing. It may be that the content that is in their results is causing an error with your Display Template.

Comment: Thanks. The issue was resolved with a weird trick. I had to give all my users edit access to the site rather than read-only. Not sure why, but it did work.

Comment: That's not a fix. Read is all they "should" need. Are you certain that you published your display templates?

Comment: Yes. I did publish my display template. Read works well in my PROD environment. In stage somehow it didn't work.

Comment: OK, if it were me I'd troubleshoot that problem. Changing permissions is not really a "fix" it is just masking the problem.